# groupby - selecting only certain groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the below DataFrame, I want to select the **Services** where there are less than 2 'Healthy' instances of that service. In this case I want the Series (EmailService, UserService, NotificationService)

```
              CPU              Service  Memory   Status
IP                                                     
10.22.11.150   13       StorageService      55  Healthy
10.22.11.90    23       StorageService      19  Healthy
10.22.11.91    10         EmailService      44  Healthy
10.22.11.92    69          UserService       1  Healthy
10.22.11.93    63  NotificationService      81  Healthy
10.22.11.93    87  NotificationService      98  Unhealthy
```

I think I need this grouping,

```
grouped = servers_df.groupby('Service')
```

but not sure how to count the Status column and then get the result based on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with lambda function for count `Healthy` and compare, last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby('Service')['Status'].transform(lambda x: (x=='Healthy').sum() < 2)]
print (df)
             CPU              Service  Memory     Status
IP                                                      
10.22.11.91   10         EmailService      44    Healthy
10.22.11.92   69          UserService       1    Healthy
10.22.11.93   63  NotificationService      81    Healthy
10.22.11.93   87  NotificationService      98  Unhealthy
```

If want check only 1 value `Healthy` per group use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` for all dupes and chain it with condition for compare `Healthy` for filter out multiple `Unhealthy`, then invert condition by `~` and filter `boolean indexing` again:

```
df = df[~(df.duplicated(['Service','Status'], keep=False) & (df['Status'] == 'Healthy'))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html).

```
df.groupby("Service").filter(lambda x: len(x[x.Status == "Healthy"]) < 2)
```

Might be slower in speed according to [jezrael's experiment in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41821495/2901002)

Another way: using `apply` (modified from jezrael's transform solution)

```
df.groupby('Service').apply(
                   lambda x: x if (x.Status == 'Healthy').sum() < 2 else None)


                        IP         CPU  Service              Memory Status
Service                     
EmailService        2   10.22.11.91 10  EmailService         44 Healthy
NotificationService 4   10.22.11.93 63  NotificationService  81 Healthy
                    5   10.22.11.93 87  NotificationService  98 Unhealthy
UserService         3   10.22.11.92 69  UserService          1  Healthy
```

Comment: Unfortunately `filter` is really slow :(

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
s=df[df.Status=='Healthy'].groupby('Service').Service.count().lt(2)
df.loc[df.Service.isin(s[s].index)]

    IP          CPU Service             Memory  Status
2   10.22.11.91 10  EmailService        44      Healthy
3   10.22.11.92 69  UserService         1       Healthy
4   10.22.11.93 63  NotificationService 81      Healthy
5   10.22.11.93 87  NotificationService 98      Unhealthy
```

Comment: @Tai yep let me fix